# How to prevent burst photos in camera timer?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios, camera

- I can tap the upper-central "live photos" (short video) icon button to assure live mode is disabled.
- I can assure I'm switched to "Photo" and not "Video" or "Square" or whatever.
- I can tap HDR to "auto" or "off" ("on" is not available for front-facing lens).
- I can set the timer to three seconds or ten seconds.
- I can try rear-facing or front-facing lens.
- I can try a short tap, long tap, or double-tap of the shutter button.

But I can't seem to stop the "burst photo" mode when using the timed photo option.

I don't want to have to choose between ten "burst" shots for every single timed snapshot I take.

I also looked in device Settings / Photos & Camera, and I don't see anything relevant there.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

iPhone SE

iOS 9.3.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to stop burst mode during timer photos is to turn the flash `On`.  When the flash is `On` the camera will only take 1 picture.

My recommendation is to provide feedback to Apple [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) and let them know how you feel about this limitation.

Comment: Thank you. It seems also turning HDR to "on" prevents bursts, but that's only available for rear-facing camera, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

When you take pictures with a timer it is very possible you won't like the first shot, so iPhones take 10 shots for you to choose the one you like the best.  Once you take the picture, open the picture, click the "select" option at the bottom, select the picture you prefer with a check mark and click done.  The iPhone will only save that picture you prefer.  Not bad right?

Comment: The interface for choosing a shot from a "burst" is cumbersome, and ten shots is overkill. If I'd the option to choose whether to take one or three or ten photos on a timer, and if they saved as separate photos (not groups/bursts), then maybe I'd like appreciate this, but Apple's bursts waste my time and storage space.

Answer (score 1):

I've sent this message to [Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html):

> **Subject: Allow setting a camera timer without Burst mode**
>
> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> The 3 or 10 second camera timer is very useful in many instances.
>   Those include instances where Burst mode is not required.
>   Unfortunately, there is no way to turn off Burst mode when you use the
>   camera timer.
>
> There are two workarounds:
>
> - Set flash to On.
> - Set HDR to On.
>
> Besides the annoyance of having to turn on one of those every time,
>   there are many instances where neither flash nor HDR is required. So
>   these are not acceptable workarounds either.
>
> Hopefully, it becomes possible to turn off Burst mode when you use the
>   camera timer.

Feel free to use this as a template.

Answer (score 0):

With my iPhone 4S I used to put the timer on 3 sec in order to be able to hold the camera steady for sharper photos.
Now I have the iPhone 5S with iOS 9.3.5, and detected the atomatic burst mode when using the timer on 3 sec. Very annoying!
TEST
I've switched on also HDR (together with the timer on 3 sec) and the burst mode disappeared. 
Result only 2 photo's: 
the first is a 'normal' photo [1,24 MB] and 
the second is the HDR-photo [1,15 MB].

For me this solution is O.K.  But it would be nice if you could switch of the burst mode altogether.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true turning the flash to on will prevent auto burst on self timers that is not the ONLY way, anything that forces the camera to individualize each shot will work so you can turn on Flash OR Live OR HDR