# Is it possible to take multiple, continuous photos with a delay in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

In iOS, if you hold the home botton in the `Camera` app, you can take a series of photos continuously. However, I want to use this with a delay (10 sec), and since there is a reason to use the delay I can't hold the button.

So is it possible to take a series of photos continuously, possibly the number of photos or the total time set in advance?

I use iOS 10.2.1 and would like to use it in both the main and selfie camera.

Comment: You may find this [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239495/168832) interesting.

Comment: @Monomeeth Oh that question is talking about the opposite? But I disable HDR but can't take the multiple photos. I assume that may even be just a bug, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought it may be useful to you. By reading through the answers and comments it seems you need to make sure the flash is off for burst mode to work. Worth a try.

Comment: @Monomeeth Of course I tried but it didn't work. I see it is strange for the burst mode to be enabled if you disable the flush.

Comment: There's a time-lapse option, isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this thread by researching something for another answer. Just to update this - as of iOS/iPadOS 15 you can easily acchieve what the OP looks for using Apple’s ShortCuts:

[image]

Adjust the parameters and save it to your home screen.

Comment: WIth some additional actions, you can even make it configurable by asking the user for the repeat and wait values :-)

Comment: For those who came here from Google: open thr Apple Shortcuts application which may be named as "Commands" in some localizations, then create a new script: open camera preview  + [repeat + take a photo + save to recent], save to home screen. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good app to do this called "Lapse-It". It is free with a paid upgrade, but the free mode will do what you ask.

Comment: Is this a camera app? It just clocks the timer but didn't take any photos. I even don't know how to use it.

Comment: You're right. I was confusing my two time lapse apps. I've now corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know Its bit late guys, [PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) is a sample project provided by Apple which does exactly what you are looking for. Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to respond to this, but for anyone that looks for an answer, I found an app called 'Skyflow' that is mainly for time-lapse, but it does the job in this case and you can export your shots/frames in an image format (e.g. JPEG). Please note I did this with iPhone and with a Windows computer. The photos go to iTunes and you can access them through iTunes-obviously you need to install iTunes on Windows, connect you iPhone to your computer and access the 'File sharing', go to the 'Skyflow' app, from there and save the folder to your computer. The link to use 'File sharing' on iTunes:
https://youtu.be/kRF3lBqSOJA
I hope it helps.